# Mapping the contents of an AWS S3 object to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I have an AWS object which is a text file containing the following numbers, each in a new row: `4 5 8 2 1 3` I want to read through the AWS object and map the numbers to an array and print them out in a view. However, the `to_a` method creates an error. I've searched through the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html), but nowhere can I find details behind mapping object contents to an array.

For reference, when I run the following code in my view I receive the below results: `<%= @bucket.objects.first.read.inspect %>`

`"4\n5\n8\n2\n1\n3\n\r\n"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using split:

```
def to_array
  read.gsub("\r", "").split("\n").map(&:to_i)
end

<%= @bucket.objects.first.to_array %>
```

Comment: That gives the following results: `["4", "5", "8", "2", "1", "3", "\r"]` - which is an array of strings? I need an array on integers

Answer (score 1):

`<%= @bucket.objects.first.read.each_line.map(&:to_i) %>`

`each_line` reads each line of the input. `map(&:to_i)` iterates through each line and converts each string to an integer, ignoring any trailing whitespace and newlines.

Comment: `lines` throws an error: undefined method `lines' for #<AWS::S3::S3Object:0x007ff6be75d4f8>